# Cannot be used for return type error when querying via any API call

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm getting an error that I cant seem to get around when calling my API.  The error being throwin is:

```
    System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String]]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]]'
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, String paramName)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
```

When the API call is submitted using an organization id, its supposed to grab all locations associated with that id.  Thats when this error is kicked up.  I can't for the life of me find what is causing it.  The details on the call are as follows:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/getorganizationlocations")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrganizationLoc(int id)
    {
        var organizationNames = await _repo.GetOrganizationNameById(id);

        return Ok(organizationNames);
    }
```

Repository:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetOrganizationNameById(int LocationId)
{
    var OrganizationName = await _context.Locations
                .Include(l => l.Owners)
                .Where(o => o.Id == LocationId)
                .Select(l => l.Owners.Select(on => on.Owner.OrganizationName))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return OrganizationName;
}
```

Repository Interface:

```
public interface IOrganizationRepository
{
    void Add<T>(T entity) where T: class;
    void Delete<T>(T entity) where T: class;
    Task<bool> SaveAll();
    Task<IEnumerable<Organizations>> GetOrganizations();
    Task<Organizations> GetOrganization(int id);
    Task<OrgToLoc> GetOwnees(int OrganizationId, int LocationId);

    // Begin Help on many to many 
    Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetOrganizationNameById(int LocationId);
    // End help many to many
}
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this to occur?

When in debugging, the request is executed in the controller and as I step through it, the error is thrown after the controller requests the details from the repository and returns the data to the controller.  It gets hung up on here and throws the error:

```
var organizationNames = await _repo.GetOrganizationNameById(id);
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Comment: dotnet core version 3.0.101 and EF Core version 3.0.0.  I have googled the question yes, but nothing is coming up surrounding this issue.  There are some similar posed question that mention it has to do with not being a async method, but it is async within my project.

Comment: I am sorry but FirstOrDefault means a SINGLE entity and that is exactly the error you are getting... The error states that you have IQueryable<string> and not IQueryble<IEnumerable<string>>..... so yes you are returning a single string when it is expecting a collection of string

Comment: So basically you have two options: You change public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetOrganizationNameById(int LocationId)........... to return Task<string> or you change FirstOrDefault for ToList

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  Changing it to ToListAsync worked but threw a conversion error.  I ended up needing to change .Select to .SelectMany within the repository.  This got it working and its not returning the correct data.  Thanks again for the push in the right direction on this.

Comment: I think your query can work if you upgrade to 3.1.3

Comment: `dotnet core version 3.0.101 and EF Core version 3.0.0. I have googled the question yes, but nothing is coming up surrounding this issue.` The first link was the exact same one listed in the answer. https://www.google.com/search?q=System.ArgumentException%3A+Expression+of+type+%27System.Threading.Tasks.Task%601%5BSystem.Linq.IQueryable%601%5BSystem.String%5D%5D%27+cannot+be+used+for+return+type+%27System.Threading.Tasks.Task%601%5BSystem.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%601%5BSystem.String%5D%5D%27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I want to to apologize because you are right.  Your query is correct!

Second I created an app and found the problem:

This is a known bug in EF 3.0.0 here is [Issue at GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18181)

I was able to fix the issue by going to Manage Nuget Packages and upgrading 3 packages to the lastest version of ER Core 3.1.3

[image]

After upgrading those 3 packages everything worked.

Your query is not the problem.

Comment: Ahhhhh good to know!  I'm a beginner when it comes to these things (and I'm learning through building my own web app using .NET CORE as the API and Angular for the front end).  I'm glad to see there was another underlaying issues here.  Thanks for the follow up!

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan Alfaro mentioned, the answer was to change the FirstOrDefaultAsync in the repository to ToListAsync.  This did cause another conversion error to be thrown however:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

This was resolved by changing .Select to .SelectMany.  The working version is as such:

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetOrganizationNameById(int LocationId)
{
    var OrganizationName = await _context.Locations
                .Include(l => l.Owners)
                .Where(o => o.Id == LocationId)
                .SelectMany(l => l.Owners.Select(on => on.Owner.OrganizationName))
                .ToListAsync();

    return OrganizationName;
}
```

Comment: Hey check my answer I found this is a known bug.  After upgrading to EF 3.1.3 it went away on my testing.